# Vim syntax iskeyword command add @ symbol

Tags: vim, syntax, vim-syntax-highlighting

I would like to highlight the @prefix directive in the RDF Turtle syntax.

I have added a syntax group turtleKeyword which includes the word @prefix using the Vim command `sy keyword`. Unfortunately, this does not yet work because the default Vim keyword characters do not include @. So I am trying to add the @ symbol to the Vim keyword characters in a Turtle syntax file.

I found the command `sy iskeyword` defines the keyword characters, but as an option to the command, the @ symbol itself stands for all alphabetic characters.

What option to `sy iskeyword` includes the @ symbol in the definition of keyword characters?

Comment: Does it work after `set iskeyword+=@-@`?

Comment: @dlmeetei That does it, thank you! Do you want to post that as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Done, glad that it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `isfname` and `iskeyword` options have the same format of options. The format has a predefined meaning for `@` which represent any characters that `isalpha()` returns `true`. More details at `help isf`.

Hence, to include '@' itself, we need to use `@-@` for '@'.

Including `@-@` in your `iskeyword` as below should fix the issue

```
 set iskeyword+=@-@
```